# Change the color of point on click and keep it unchanged using R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to work on creating the graph using plotly. When the user clicks on any geom_point in the plot using R shiny, it should change the color and keep it unchanged.

Currently, my code is working fine. When the user clicks on any geom_point in the plot, it is changing the color. But when I click on another geom_point, the previous point which was highlighted goes back to its original color.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)
    library(htmlwidgets)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      plotlyOutput("plot")
    )


    javascript <- "
    function(el, x){
      el.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
        colors = [];

        var base_color = document.getElementsByClassName('legendpoints')[data.points[0].curveNumber].getElementsByTagName('path')[0].style['stroke']
        for (var i = 0; i < data.points[0].data.x.length; i += 1) {
          colors.push(base_color)
        };
        colors[data.points[0].pointNumber] = '#FF00FF';
        Plotly.restyle(el,
                       {'marker':{color: colors}},
                       [data.points[0].curveNumber]
                      );
      });
    }"


    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      nms <- row.names(mtcars)

      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, col = as.factor(cyl), key = nms)) + 
          geom_point()
        ggplotly(p) %>% onRender(javascript)

      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expect when the user clicks on any geom_point, it should change the color and that color should remain until he closes the shiny app. the color should not return to its original color. Maybe there is a minor change to be made to the Javascript function. Thanks!

Comment: There is one point for each subclass which stays colored

Comment: @AlexanderLeow I am sorry I am new to shiny and R. I did not understand you. could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you always set all point to the base color instead of check which color actual points have. I am no javascript expert but this works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)


javascript <- "
function(el, x){
  el.on('plotly_click', function(data) {
    var colors = [];
    // check if color is a string or array
    if(typeof data.points[0].data.marker.color == 'string'){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.points[0].data.marker.color.length; i++) {
        colors.push(data.points[0].data.marker.color);
      }
    } else {
      colors = data.points[0].data.marker.color;
    }
    // some debugging
    //console.log(data.points[0].data.marker.color)
    //console.log(colors)

    // set color of selected point
    colors[data.points[0].pointNumber] = '#FF00FF';
    Plotly.restyle(el,
      {'marker':{color: colors}},
      [data.points[0].curveNumber]
    );
  });
}
"

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  nms <- row.names(mtcars)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, col = as.factor(cyl), key = nms)) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% onRender(javascript)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```